# checking permissions in custom account authenticator

Tags: android, android-account, android-authenticator

i have a custom authenticator, and i'd like to expose the user / password to other applications. to protect from any random app obtaining the credentials, i'd like to perform something like a permissions check in my custom authenticator's `getAuthToken()` method. what's the correct method?

i tried this,

```
    int p = context.checkCallingPermission("com.whatever.AUTH");
    if (p != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
```

where "com.whatever.AUTH" is defined in the app hosting my authenticator,

```
<permission android:name="com.vmware.horizon.AUTH" />
```

however, in my test app that does not have a `uses-permission` in it's manifest, when i request the account,

```
    AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future = am.getAuthToken(new Account(
            "com.whatever", "com.whatever"),
            "com.whatever", new Bundle(), this,
            new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>() {

                @Override
                public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future) {
                                        String token  = result.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);

                }
            }, handler);
```

i successfully obtain the auth token. debugging shows that the call through to my authenticator's `getAuthToken()` method happens, but the check permission call returned "granted".

EDIT: if i get the package name from the context i'm using to call `checkCallingPermission()` it is the package name of the app hosting the custom authenticator. if i get the calling PID, UID they are 0 and 1000, respectively.

any ideas?

Comment: What is the context when you are using `Context.checkCallingPermission`

Comment: Couldn't you use a Content Provider to handle all the permission checking for you?

Comment: @wsanville i don't know what that means. i need to check the permission from withink my custom authenticator. i have no control as to when / how that this called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When looking at the Android source code, I noticed that the account manager service sets the caller's pid and uid on the Bundle as `AccountManager.KEY_CALLER_PID` and `AccountManager.KEY_CALLER_UID`.

You can use `getInt()` on the bundle to find out the real caller's pid and uid in your getAppToken method.

One other useful bit of information that can be hard to find. The `getAppToken` method is often only called once since the account manager service caches the result. If you want to be able to manage the token more actively, you can disable caching by adding meta-data to your manifest entry:

```
<service android:name=".authenticator.AccountAuthenticatorService">
  <meta-data android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator" android:resource="@xml/authenticator"/>
  <meta-data android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator.customTokens" android:value="1"/>
</service>
```

Here is what the authenticator xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<account-authenticator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:accountType="com.your.account.type"
  android:customTokens="true"
  android:icon="@drawable/logo"
  android:smallIcon="@drawable/logo"
  android:label="@string/app_name_long"/>
```